# Calling OS settings from C#

Tags: c#

For my program, I would like to click a button and have the user be able to access certain settings of their computer.

I have no idea about how to access the OS at all. Other questions assume that the readers have a basic understanding of this . I have none and need someone to give me a link or a full explanation on how to do this and why there answer works.

So if they select Date Settings Buttons I will like the following Window to show:[image]

I have no idea how to get certain settings to show. Any help would be welcomed

Comment: No, this deals with C#, and that answer assumes that the reader knows a lot more. I am asking for the very basics of accessing the OS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[How to open various Settings pages directly in Windows 10](http://winaero.com/blog/how-to-open-various-settings-pages-directly-in-windows-10/) describes the commands to open settings with the run console.

> Battery Saver --> ms-settings:batterysaver
>
> Battery Saver Settings --> ms-settings:batterysaver-settings
>
> ...

Use such a command with the [Process.Start-Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.start(v=vs.110).aspx) and open the required settings. For example the Windows update settings will open with

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("ms-settings:windowsupdate");
```

or the requested date settings with

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("ms-settings:dateandtime");
```

Answer (score 1):

You need:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("ms-settings:dateandtime");
```